# Time complexity of Minimum number of squares whose sum equals to given number n

Tags: time-complexity

What is the exact time complexity of this code ?

I know its exponential but what kind of exponential like 2^n , sqrt(n) ^ sqrt(n) etc.

If attach some proof, that would be great.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-squares-whose-sum-equals-to-given-number-n/

```
class squares { 
    // Returns count of minimum squares that sum to n 
    static int getMinSquares(int n) 
    { 
        // base cases 
        if (n <= 3) 
            return n; 

        // getMinSquares rest of the table using recursive 
        // formula 
        int res = n; // Maximum squares required is 
        // n (1*1 + 1*1 + ..) 

        // Go through all smaller numbers 
        // to recursively find minimum 
        for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) { 
            int temp = x * x; 
            if (temp > n) 
                break; 
            else
                res = Math.min(res, 1 + getMinSquares(n - temp)); 
        } 
        return res; 
    } 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println(getMinSquares(6)); 
    } 
}
```

In my opinion, since each for loop is calling the same recursion for sqrt(n) number of time and each call is for (n - x*x)) ~ n...

So it should be n ^ sqrt(n).

Is this answer correct ?

Comment: It should be something like: `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2^2) + T(n-3^2) + ... + T(n-n) + c*(n-sqrt(n))`

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation for that function is

```
T(n) = sum from i=1 to i=sqrt(n) of T(n - i*i)
```

which is bounded above by

```
T(n) = sqrt(n) * T(n-1)
```

as each term in the sum above will be at most `T(n-1)` and there are `sqrt(n)` of them. `T(n) = sqrt(n) * T(n-1)` is `O( sqrt(n)^n )`. I'm sure there is some clever way to get a better bound, but this function looks like it is exponential.